# slice to create 2 dimensional array

Tags: reactjs, slice

I want to create a 2 dimensional array

- array `items` has 32 objects
- every array contains 9 objects each with the remainder (32 % 9 = **5**) in the last array

with the code below, I am expecting :
I am expecting : **[Array(9), Array(9), Array(9), Array(5)]**

```
 const returnProductsArrays = (items) => { 
          let TwoDimensionalArray = []
          let remainder = items.length % 9
          let i = 0
          while (i < (items.length - remainder)) { 
            let array = items.slice(i, 9)
            TwoDimensionalArray.push(array)
            i += 9 
          }
          const array = items.slice(i + 1, remainder)
          TwoDimensionalArray.push(array)
          return TwoDimensionalArray
        }
```

only the 1st array has objects, the rest is empty.

[image]
[image]

What am I am missing ?
slice does not mutate vs. splice . why is the array empty on the 2 iteration in the while loop

Answer (score 2):

there are two mistakes, I will point below:

```
const returnProductsArrays = (items) => { 
          let TwoDimensionalArray = []
          let remainder = items.length % 9
          let i = 0
          while (i < (items.length - remainder)) {
            // second param needs to be "i + 9"
            let array = items.slice(i, i + 9)
            TwoDimensionalArray.push(array)
            i += 9 
          }
          // here you need just the "i" param (not i+1), and it will slice till the end of array 
          const array = items.slice(i)
          TwoDimensionalArray.push(array)
          return TwoDimensionalArray
        }
```